# get mails in a conversation for exchange mails

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I want to retrieve all mails in a conversation when a user selects an email.

I know that I can use this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869870(v=office.15).aspx, but for some microsoft exchange accounts, getrootitems returning zero.

So, is there any other way that works for microsoft exchange ?

More details:
My outlook showing "Online with microsoft exchange" at bottom right.

Below process is slow  as I have 1000's of mails in inbox, so this wont help me.

IEnumerable mail = 
        folder.Items.OfType().Where(m => m.Subject == "Test").Select(m => m);

Comment: is this what you are looking for [MSDN how to Get conversation items by using EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220497(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a ton, let me try.

Comment: Getting error - the autodiscover service couldn't be located. Do I need to run any server ? Btw, its an online exchange account that I configured to outlook.

Answer (score 1):

The [GetRootItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866457(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Conversation class has the following description in MSDN:

*If all items are deleted from the conversation after the Conversation object has been obtained, GetRootItems returns a SimpleItems collection with zero objects. In this case, the Count property of the SimpleItems collection returns 0.*

Try to use the cached exchange mode instead.

Comment: Actually I didnt delete any emails. Even "show as conversation" in outlook showing conversation with all mails.   Can you please suggest me if its possbible at all. You think ews managed api works for me ?

Please try to answer this new one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191993/registry-keys-for-building-addin-using-visual-studio-installer

Comment: It depends on where you are going to run the code. If you develop an Outlook add-in you need to use the Outlook object model.

Comment: Its an windows forms addin that can be installed only in outlook. So, I will forget ews api. Other than that, is there any possible way of showing mails in a conversations ?

Comment: In my outlook addin, I need to grab data of all mails in a conversation. As of now, the user have to select each and every mail. So, my plan is, when user selects a single mail, grab all mails related to that conversation and process them.

What I meant by show as conversations is, in outlook, click "View" and then check the box "show as conversations". This is showing me mails grouped by conversation. That means, they are there and not deleted. 

One main thing is, outlook shows "online with microsoft exchange" at the bottom right, may be you get some idea with this.