# Registry keys for building addin using visual studio installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, windows-installer, outlook-addin

I was able to create msi installed for my c# outlook addin using visual studio installer - an extension.

This is the link I used - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx.

I successfully created addin using the above link but its not showing up in outlook because the above link didnt talk about registry keys.

So, I added registry keys based on the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

I changed "installdir" to "targetdir" because visual studio installed had set the property as targetdir where installdir property is if we build using installshield.

So, even thats pointing to correct install dir and addin is loading in outlook. But it is giving error because, at first, I tried with

```
file:///[TARGETDIR]abc.vsto|vstolocal  where abc is my product name.
```

But abc.vsto is not there ( I selected "primary output" while adding project output to application folder), so outlook complaining that.

Then I tried with file:///[targetdir]abc.dll which gave me error:

```
Exception reading manifest from file:///path/to/setup/abc.dll:
manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened
```

Comment: Guys, its working by adding vsto, manifest files by clicking "add file" which is not mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article in MSDN. In general, you may also find the [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section helpful.